# Why typescript loader cause to errors in html webpack plugin?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I have the following webpack config

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    entry: "./index.ts",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: "ts-loader",
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
    },
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    },

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "index.html",
        }),
    ],
};
```

and every time when I run webpack I receive these errors however, the typescript file compiles successfully

```
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\Koder\Desktop\programingLS\Education\Topics\Web\Lessons\TypeScript\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\index.js(16,19)
      TS2306: File 'C:\Users\Koder\Desktop\programingLS\Education\Topics\Web\Lessons\TypeScript\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js' is not a module.
```

packages:
"devDependencies": {
"html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
"lodash": "^4.17.20",
"ts-loader": "^8.0.2",
"typescript": "^3.9.7",
"webpack": "^4.44.1",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
}

Comment: Can you share your code where to import lodash? It doesn't make sense since it loads from `lodash/lodash.js`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the problem with the following command:

```
npm install --save @types/html-webpack-plugin
```